# FTP Mode for SFTP Plugin in Sublime Text 2

Tags: ftp, sublimetext2, sublimetext

Is it possible to set the FTP mode to ASCII in the SFTP plugin for Sublime?

It seems to be using Binary by default which is causing problems for us when pushing up from Windows to Unix.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately PSFTP ( the client used by the SFTP plugin on windows ) cannot use ASCII mode.

See [the FAQ of PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/faq.html#faq-pscp-ascii) for further info.